# get only specific field based on filter from mongodb using python

Tags: python, mongodb

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

sdate = date(2021, 7, 15)   # start date
edate = date(2021, 8, 29)   # end date

delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta
a=[]
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    a.append(day)

b=[]
for i in range(len(a)):
    b.append(str(a[i]))
```

> #b is list of dates

```
import urllib.parse
import pandas as pd
from pymongo import MongoClient
host= "hostname" ; Port= "27017"
username = urllib.parse.quote_plus('username')
password = urllib.parse.quote_plus("admin123")
client = MongoClient('mongodb://%s:%s@servername/?authSource=admin' % (username, password))
db = client["my_db"]
col = db["region_report"]
data_report=[]
```

> #till here every thing is fine

```
for i in range (len(b)):
    data_report.extend(col.find({'Day': b[i],'Brand': 'brand_name'}))
```

> here in "data_report" I am getting complete table which include all
> the fields like Day, name, State_name, Skill, Brand etc based on
> applied filter where 'Day' and 'Brand' matches but I need only
> 'State_name' column to be searched as bringing comlete data and filtering it is
> comsuming time.

```
data_report=pd.DataFrame(data_report)
    
output_data=set(data_report["State_name"])
```

> this is my current code how i am extracting 'State_name' from the
> whole data which is not efficient and consuming time. So I am looking for a more optimised
> mongodb query.

Comment: have you tried mongo `projection`? `.find({'Day': b[i],'Brand': 'brand_name'}, {'State_name':1} )`

Comment: yes but i guess that will only work if if i define the "State_name" like 
col.find({"State_name":"some_name},{filters}) but the State_name changes every time so that can't be defined.

Comment: what do you mean by state_name changes everytime? `{'State_name':1} ` in `.find({'Day': b[i],'Brand': 'brand_name'}, {'State_name':1} )` means take only `State_name` columns

Comment: i am looking for the code to collect State_name where day and brand name matches like:
correct_brand correct_date State1
correct_brand correct_date State2
wrong_brand wrong_date State3
query should return State1,State2

Comment: I just realized i was putting the value earlier and need to be defined after the filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x=[]
for i in range (len(b)):
    x.extend(col.find({'Day': b[i],'Brand': 'Brand_name'},{"State_name":1}))
```

> here {'Day': b[i],'Brand': 'Brand_name'} are the filters which are
> checking if data qualifies the filter scheme and {"State_name":1}
> represents the column which are to be searched, and then we can use
> 'x' where data is stored.